# Destroying a dialog when it loses focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a program where I have jQuery UI dialogs. I wish that those dialogs would be closed when they lose focus e.g. the user clicks anywhere outside the dialogs in question.

On the surface this seems like a simple problem, but the `blur` event didn't work at all. After that I moved on to `focusin` and `focusout`, but stumbled upon a strange problem:

When I have a dialog and have attached `focusin` and `focusout` to the element containing the dialog (the parent of the element I called `dialog` on). The first click after the dialog's appearing ALWAYS produces a `focusout` event regardless of where the click lands.

So if I would like to destroy the dialog on `focusout`, the dialog gets destroyed when it shouldn't be. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DB4E7/1/) that demonstrates my problem.

I know I could use some trick to ignore the first `focusout`, but I'd like to know if there is any way to get this working the right way, which is that the only event is produced when the user clicks outside the dialog for the first time.

#### UPDATE:

I found an agreeable answer to my question with the help of `underscore.js`:

I broke my problem down to parts:

1. A `focusout` happens on the first click
2. If the click was OUTSIDE the dialog, there were no further events
3. If the click was INSIDE the dialog, a `focusin` event followed

So the undesired behavior took place when there was a sequence of `focusout`->`focusin`. I used underscore's `defer` function and a boolean modifier to tackle this problem

```
onFocusout: function(event) {
  console.log('focus out');
  this.hasFocus = false;
  var self = this;
  _.defer(function() {
    if (!self.hasFocus) alert('DESTROY DIALOG');
  });
},

onFocusin: function() {
  console.log('focus in');
  this.hasFocus = true;
},
```

`defer` makes the function wait until the call stack has cleared (in the bad behaving case, there is a `focusin` event waiting in the stack) and then executes it. So if `onFocusin` is fired right after `onFocusout` the `hasFocus` variable is changed to `true` and the deferred function will not destroy the dialog!

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 6):

An option that would probably work better is to listen for clicks anywhere on the page and close the dialog if one occurs outside the dialog area. Something like:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var clickedOnDialog = $(e.srcElement)
         .closest(".ui-widget.ui-dialog") // these classes are fixed
         .children(".ui-dialog-content") // this as well
         .is(".dialog"); // this is your own class

    if (!clickedOnDialog) {
        $('.dialog').dialog('destroy');
    }
});
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhnju/).

Comment: Or even better: `$(document).on("click", ":not(.dialog)", function(e) { $('.dialog').dialog('destroy'); });`.

Comment: @freakish: I 'm not sure about that, what if you click on e.g. the dialog's title bar?

Comment: Hmm, somehow I can't make it work. Tried with custom classes as well. Please note, that in your solution if you click next to buttons ( but still on popup ) it will close as well. So I guess the best solution is to use `dialogClass` option on dialog and refer to the class.

Comment: @freakish: Quite true. I updated the solution and fiddle, now it will work no matter where you click.

Comment: your approach is innovative, although I don't want to catch every click from my document, still worth a +1

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, for a jQuery modal dialog, it places a div with the class `ui-widget-overlay` on top of your content.  Therefore, I just did something like this:

```
$(".ui-widget-overlay").live("click", function() {
    $("#myDialogDiv").dialog("close");
});
```

It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

blur should work for you:

```
$('.dialog').trigger('click');
$('.dialog').blur(function() {
   this.dialog('destroy');
}
```

Comment: with blur, if i decide to make my first click to the outside of the dialog, the blur event doesn't trigger. So the user has to first click the dialog and then click outside. Otherwise it works perfectly. But it isn't sufficient!

Comment: the dialog has focus, this is proved by a focusin event launched when i initialize it. So smashing a `focus` in is not going to cut it.

Comment: how about triggering click at the begining ?

Comment: Preferably I don't want to trigger any extra events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround, it works in a page with multiple dialogs too, also updated solution of jquery 'live' method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function() {
    var dialogAria = $(this).next().attr('aria-describedby');        
    $('#'+dialogAria).dialog("close");
});
```

i've been inspired by [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402019/destroying-a-dialog-when-it-loses-focus/13867355#13867355)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, this is fairly straight forward. The way that jQuery structures its dialogs is that whenever a dialog becomes active, it places a div that covers all of your other page content and has a class of .ui-widget-overlay and it has a z-index of x (in my case, 100). Whenever a dialog becomes active, it will give that dialog, and that dialog only a z-index of x + 1.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function () {
    var overlay = $(this);
    var dialogToClose = null;
    $.each($(".dialog"), function () {
        if ($(this).zIndex() == (overlay.zIndex() + 1)){
            dialogToClose = $(this);
        }
    });
    dialogToClose.dialog("close");
});
```